# open: Invalid argument in direct I/O

Tags: alignment, aio

I was trying to make a [AIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) practice via [kernel AIO API](http://lse.sourceforge.net/io/aio.html). Here is some code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* syscall() not POSIX */
#define ALIGN_SIZE 4096
#define RD_WR_SIZE 1024

/* ... */

/* Make the alignment according to page size to validate open() */
posix_memalign(&buf, ALIGN_SIZE, RD_WR_SIZE);
fd = open("aio_test_file", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_DIRECT, 0644);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open");
    return -1;
}
/* ... */
```

But my `open()` calling still fail:

```
open: Invalid argument
```

I have searched that error. Some of them says that you must make the alignment in the case of direct I/O. By using the command:

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep -i "block size"
```

I got the `block size` is 4096. But why the open() calling still fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html):

> O_DIRECT support was added under Linux in kernel version 2.4.10. Older
>   Linux kernels simply ignore this flag. Some file systems may not
>   implement the flag and open() will fail with EINVAL if it is used.

That would be my first guess.

Comment: Yep.  It's probably the file system.

Comment: I have test the code in CentOS, it works well, the only difference is it's `block size` is 1024. But while I change the alignment to 512 or 256, the code still works well. I'll do some more research on that issue.

Comment: It may be more a case of the type of your filesystem and your kernel version.  Is it an ext4 filesystem on CentOS 6?

Comment: My origin test(the fail test) is build on Mint, it's a Ubuntu-kernel Linux release. By using `df -T`, I find it's file system is `ext4`, is  direct I/O can not work on Ext4?